# Elasticsearch and NEST: Filtering with Lookups

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.7.x (and NEST 1.7.2) and trying to take advantage of filtering with lookups as documented here: [Terms Filter Lookup](https://www.elastic.co/blog/terms-filter-lookup).  I'm able to craft the JSON by hand for the request I desire and execute it using Sense.  Works great, awesome feature!  However, in the NEST library, I don't see a way to create such a terms clause.  For example, from the link referenced above, I can do something like:

```
"terms" : {
   "proteins" : {
      "index" : "microarrays",
      "type" : "experiment",
      "id" : "experiment1234",
      "path" : "upregulated_proteins"
   },
   "_cache_key" : "experiment_1234"
}
```

Is there a way to build this query using NEST?  If not, is there a way I can inject some JSON into a NEST query as I'm building it?  I don't know if NEST 2.x+ supports this but upgrading to ES 2.x is a longer term plan for us and I'd like to leverage functionality that is already available in ES 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome, I've already received an answer from [Greg Marzouka](https://github.com/gmarz) of Elastic!  He says:

> It's mapped as TermsLookup() or TermsLookupFilter in 1.x. Check out the [unit tests](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/1.x/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/Filter/Singles/TermsLookupFilterJson.cs) for some examples.

```
client.Search<Paper>(s => s
   .Query(q => q
      .Filtered(fq => qf
         .Filter(f => f
            .CacheKey("experiment_1234")
            .TermsLookup(t => t
               .Lookup<Protein>(p => p.UnregulatedProteins, "experiment1234", "microarrays", "experiment") 
            )
         )
      )
   ));
```

> In 2.x it's a little more aligned with the ES query DSL.

Comment: As a corollary, for the 1.7 version of the NEST library, there's bug that makes it tricky to get the cache cleared when needed.  Here's a link from the NEST team that describes how that can be worked around: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2229